# Favoriting an election candidate during nomination phase

Tags: feature-request, election

I've been reviewing the nominations for the moderator election going on on StackOverflow.  As I'm reading through them, it would be really nice to mark a candidate as one I will consider once the nominations are over. Right now, I have to write the name somewhere and find them again when it's time to vote.

Comment: When the primary phase starts all the nominations and the comments beneath them will remain, which should make it a lot easier...

Comment: Why don't you just get into discussions with them? This way you will always remember the right candidate.

Comment: Would you really vote for someone you can't even remember the name for a few days?

Comment: I would. I'm terrible with names and after reading 20 or more profiles, I ha. Would have to retread the nominations to remember if it was one I liked. Seems to me an easy fix to add the ability to star a candidate for easy reference later.

Comment: @Robbert: why not to just bookmark candidate's profile page?

Comment: Bookmarking works. Just need to do it on the same device. It's not a huge deal, it's not like elections happen all the time. This is more a a nice to have feature.